# WCF Service with PerSession acts like PerCall

Tags: c#, wcf, session

My service:

```
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        int i = 0;

        public int Add(int value)
        {
            i += value;

            return i;
        }
    }
```

With the interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    int Add(int value);
}
```

Everytime I call the Add method the variable i gets reset to 0.
 (I tested it with WCF Test Client and a ChannelFactory)

I use a BacisHttp binding.

What did I do wrong?

Do i have to config the WCF Test Client and the ChannelFactory?

Comment: What is the value passed in the parameter "value"?

Comment: It's just a test method. The only purpose of value is, that it will be added to i

Comment: Have you added <reliableSession enabled="true" /> in web.config ?

Comment: @TobiasH - Are you creating a new client each time you make the call, or reusing an existing client?

Comment: I couldn't add <reliableSession enabled="true" />, it wasn't allowed

And no, I create the Channel only once

Answer (score 3):

I am an Idiot: BacisHttpBinding doesn't support sessions